# Не могу установить python-webtest

Tags: python, ubuntu

При попытке установки получаю:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-webtest
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово

python-webtest is already the newest version.

Будут установлены следующие дополнительные пакеты:

  apport python-software-properties

Пакеты, которые будут обновлены:

  apport python-software-properties

обновлено 2, установлено 0 новых пакетов, для удаления отмечено 0 пакетов, и 15 пакетов не обновлено.
не установлено до конца или удалено 120 пакетов.
Необходимо скачать 0 B/232 kB архивов.
После данной операции, объём занятого дискового пространства возрастёт на 4 096 B.

Хотите продолжить? [Д/н] д

(Чтение базы данных … на данный момент установлен 205681 файл и каталог.)
Preparing to unpack …/apport_2.14.1-0ubuntu3.15_all.deb ...

  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 63

    except (IOError, OSError), e:
                             ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

dpkg: предупреждение: подпроцесс старый сценарий pre-removal возвратил код ошибки 1
dpkg: попытка использовать сценарий из нового пакета …
  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 63
    except (IOError, OSError), e:

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives
/apport_2.14.1-0ubuntu3.15_all.deb (--unpack):

 подпроцесс новый сценарий pre-removal возвратил код ошибки 1

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>

    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \

  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>

    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser

ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'

dpkg: ошибка при очистке:

 подпроцесс установлен сценарий post-installation возвратил код ошибки 1

Preparing to unpack …/python-software-properties_0.92.37.5_all.deb ...

  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 63

    except (IOError, OSError), e:
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

dpkg: предупреждение: подпроцесс старый сценарий pre-removal возвратил код ошибки 1

dpkg: попытка использовать сценарий из нового пакета …

  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 63

    except (IOError, OSError), e:
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python-software-properties_0.92.37.5_all.deb (--unpack):

 подпроцесс новый сценарий pre-removal возвратил код ошибки 1
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>

    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \

  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>

    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser

ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'

dpkg: ошибка при очистке:

 подпроцесс установлен сценарий post-installation возвратил код ошибки 1

При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:

 /var/cache/apt/archives/apport_2.14.1-0ubuntu3.15_all.deb

 /var/cache/apt/archives/python-software-properties_0.92.37.5_all.deb

W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://download.opensuse.org/repositories
/home:/tabos-team:/release/xUbuntu_14.04/  Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists
/download.opensuse.org_repositories_home:_tabos-team:_release_xUbuntu%5f14.04_Packages)

W: Вы можете запустить «apt-get update» для исправления этих ошибок

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: что-то у вас с питоном в системе явно не в порядке. возможно, что-то устанавливали из совсем уж «пионерских» репозиториев (какой-нибудь супер-новый питон3 или что-то в этом духе). я бы рекомендовал попробовать «вернуть всё назад».

Answer (score 2):

что-то у вас с питоном в системе явно не в порядке. возможно, что-то устанавливали из совсем уж «пионерских» репозиториев (какой-нибудь супер-новый python3 или что-то в этом духе). я бы рекомендовал попробовать «вернуть всё назад».

узнать, где находится файл, запускающийся по имени `python`, можно так (здесь и далее примерные ответы):

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

в моём (и, вероятно, и в вашем) случае это — символическая ссылка. куда она указывает, можно узнать так:

```
$ readlink -f $(which python)
/usr/bin/python2.7
```

проверить принадлежность этого файла пакету можно так:

```
$ dpkg -S $(readlink -f $(which python))
python2.7-minimal: /usr/bin/python2.7
```