# Debian. Не работает apt-get install

Tags: linux, debian, apt-get

При вызове команды `apt-get install -f` появляются следующие ошибки:

```
Чтение списков пакетов…
Построение дерева зависимостей…
Чтение информации о состоянии…
Следующий пакет устанавливался автоматически и больше не требуется:
  python-gpgme
Для его удаления используйте «apt-get autoremove».
обновлено 0, установлено 0 новых пакетов, для удаления отмечено 0 пакетов, и 76 пакетов не обновлено.
не установлено до конца или удалено 3 пакетов.
После данной операции, объём занятого дискового пространства возрастёт на 0 B.
Настраивается пакет python-gpgme (0.3-1+b1) …
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета python-gpgme (--configure):
 подпроцесс установлен сценарий post-installation возвратил код ошибки 1
Настраивается пакет python-simplejson (3.6.5-1) …
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета python-simplejson (--configure):
 подпроцесс установлен сценарий post-installation возвратил код ошибки 1
Настраивается пакет python-software-properties (0.92.25debian1) …
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета python-software-properties (--configure):
 подпроцесс установлен сценарий post-installation возвратил код ошибки 1
При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:
 python-gpgme
 python-simplejson
 python-software-properties
 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Что мне следует сделать с этими тремя пакетами? Переустановить? Помогите разобраться.

Comment: `apt-get install -f` а зачем так вызывать?

Comment: @edem команда автопочинки после прерванного процесса инсталляции, ЕМНИП

Comment: Это можно и добавить в пояснение к вопросу, что за пакет у Вас не установился нормально. А что такое ЕМНИП?

Comment: apt-get install -f - используется для устранения сбоев в базе пакетов вызванных нарушенными зависимостями.

Comment: весьма похоже на то, что у вас в системе стоит интерпретатор python не из репозитория дистрибутива.

Comment: Я сменил системный интерпретатор python со 2 на 3 версию. Это может являться причиной? Все работало нормально до сегодняшнего дня...

Comment: более полный ответ [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/458399/178576), но за тот ответ нет ни одного голоса, потому тот вопрос нельзя назначить дубликатом.

Answer (score 1):

Сменил версию системного интерпретатора python: `ln -sf python2 /usr/bin/python`
.
Выполнил `apt-get install -f`, затем `apt-get autoremove`

Ошибок больше нет.